# The most efficient way to produce a list of all possible hexadecimal strings with a specific length and using mask

Tags: python-3.x, list, hex, python-itertools, substitution

I have a long string with a length of 32 characters, which has the character "x" for masking. What is the most efficient way to produce a list of all possible hexadecimal strings with a specific length and using mask. We can have more than one character masking (multiple X)
For example:

If I use the following string as the input to my program,

my_string = '0011223344**x**56677889**x**aabbccddee'

I would like to have the following as the output of the program (iterating from 0 to f for each x on the input string):

```
all_possible = ['00112233440566778890aabbccddee',
                '00112233441566778890aabbccddee',
                '00112233442566778890aabbccddee',
                  ...
                '0011223344e566778890aabbccddee',
                '0011223344f566778890aabbccddee',
                '00112233440566778891aabbccddee',
                '00112233441566778892aabbccddee',
                '00112233442566778893aabbccddee',
                '00112233443566778894aabbccddee',
                  ...
                '0011223344f56677889faabbccddee'
]
```

Comment: Do you already have an inefficient way to do this?

Comment: My idea is to get the positions of the Xs by a loop, then replace the Xs with 0 and doing dynamic nested loops by keeping all the positions static and change one, I am still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <del>[`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)</del> [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `re.sub`:

```py
import re
from itertools import product

my_string = "0011223344x56677889xaabbccddee"
num_x = my_string.count("x")

for c in product("0123456789abcdef", repeat=num_x):
    i = iter(c)
    print(re.sub(r"x", lambda g: next(i), my_string))
```

Prints:

```
00112233440566778890aabbccddee
00112233440566778891aabbccddee
00112233440566778892aabbccddee
00112233440566778893aabbccddee
00112233440566778894aabbccddee
00112233440566778895aabbccddee
00112233440566778896aabbccddee

...

0011223344d56677889faabbccddee
0011223344e56677889eaabbccddee
0011223344e56677889faabbccddee
0011223344f56677889faabbccddee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension along with for loop like below:

```
my_string = '0011223344x56677889xaabbccddee'
hex_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f']
possible_outputs = [my_string]
for n in range(my_string.count('x')):
  tmp = [thestring.replace('x', str(hex), 1) for hex in hex_values for thestring in possible_outputs]
  possible_outputs.extend(tmp)
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is it gives the same value to both Xs, but they should not have the same values, the X is there to show the position to vary. So we for two XXs we have 01,02,03,...,10,11,12,....,fc,fd,fe,ff possible outputs.(Like product)

Comment: I have edited my solution, please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: I tried yours it needs more edits, I already accepted andrej answer which was very efficient.